# Uncaught ReferenceError: {Class} is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, es6-modules

Sorry if this question has already been answered, but there are so many post with this error name and a different context, that I could find the answer to this particular case.

I am using Javascript ES6 modules, and I am trying to 'compile' all my javascript files into one minified file. I am using Gulp for that. I have 3 js files (gulpfiles, an index file that require ma class, and the class file). I also have an HTML file to test the minified js file. Here is what my project looks like :

```js
// File : gulpfile.js

const { src, dest, task, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');

var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var babelify = require('babelify')
var browserify = require('browserify')
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer')
var rename = require('gulp-rename')

const jsSRC = './classes/'
const jsDEST = './output/'
const jsFILES = ['index.js']

function js(done) {
    jsFILES.map( function (entry) {
        return browserify({
            entries: [jsSRC + entry]
        })
        .transform( babelify, { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] } )
        .bundle()
        .pipe( source( entry) )
        .pipe( rename({ extname: '.min.js'}) )
        .pipe( buffer() )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( dest( jsDEST ))
    })
    done()
}

task('js',js)
task('default', parallel(js))
```

```js
// File : classes/Logger.js

class Logger{

    constructor(msg){
        console.log(msg)
    }
}
export default Logger ;
```

```js
// File : classes/index.js

import Logger from './Logger.js'

exports = { Logger }

var l = new Logger('Hello') // This should log 'Hello' in the console
```

```html
// File : demo.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="./output/index.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(I used the command  `npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env babelify browserify gulp gulp-cli gulp-rename gulp-uglify vinyl-buffer vinyl-source-stream` to install all the dependecies)

So, here is the problem. When I open the HTML file in a browser, I get the 'Hello' displayed in the console, because it is triggered by the `var l = new Logger('Hello')` line in the index.js file. But if I type the exact same thing in the console, I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Logger is not defined`

[image: Screenshot of the console]

This is probably a noob mistake. Do someone knows why I cannot use the Logger class from my page with the minified js ? And what can I do to make my class usable from the minified js file ?

Thank you !

(If there is a problem with the question, duplicated question or whatever, just tell me and I will close/delete it)

Comment: You might look at the compiled js (which may be hard given it's minimized).  But it's possible (webpack certainly does that) that the class name is not actually `Logger` after the compilation.  In the babel transpile, it may have been renamed and handed to the consumers (in the import/export process) but that does not mean it's available as `global.Logger`.  Do you need it to be available as a global?

Comment: If you need your class available globally (which is highly unlikely), you would need to add `window.Logger = Logger`

Comment: @mrrogers I looked at the compiled js (non minimized version) and yes, the class is not defined with the `Logger` name. I would like to have this class as a global class yes.
@Phil could you tell me why this is 'highly unlikely' please ?
(By the way, the window.Logger = Logger works fine, thank you)

Comment: I don't know the exact details but it comes down to the way `babel` reads and transpiles your code.  It's trying to be efficient so defining and providing functions only where they are needed based on what code is `import`ing them.  In doing that it does some name mangling tricks and does *not* just add all functions to the global namespace.   @Phil 's solution should work to get your functions available on window.

Comment: _"Highly unlikely"_ because unless you're writing some sort of UMD library, any code you write as part of your bundle will be able to use your `Logger` class by importing it. If you are writing some library for 3rd parties to use universally, then yes, you would want to make your classes available globally

Comment: Ok, this answered my question, thank you guys !